# mongodb update returns false

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update a specific record in the database. I know the record exists because find() works. But when I do an update(), the record doesn't get updated and the update returns false. Also the $params values exist in the below code. I have checked those too.

```
$d = $db->find(array("_id"=> new MongoId($id)));
echo json_encode($d);
$b = $db->update(array("_id"=>new MongoID($id)), array("$set"=>array("sector"=>$params["sector"], "center"=>$params["center"])));
echo json_encode($b);
```

Comment: which version of mongo db you are using ?

Comment: @HoqueMDZahidul - I'm using v3.0 of mongo db

Comment: @MarmiK - `update` syntax has `set`. It is there after the MongoID part

Comment: Why are you using `MongoID` (deprecated?), have you tried using the same value in the query criteria for both?

Comment: @DaveCoast - It is the same value in the query criteria for both. I have also tried by putting the value directly instead of $id variable

Comment: Have you tried single quotes around `$set`, doesn't double quotes interpret it as a variable?

Comment: @DaveCoast - Tried with single quotes too - didn't work.